# Android HDMI-DVI Video Issues

Tags: hdmi, video-out, screen-resolution

I'm having some issues getting a video signal from my [Droibox Ace](http://www.justop.com/catalog/audio-and-video/media-players-en/justop-droibox-ace-bluetooth-android-4-2-tv-box-jelly-bean-os.html). Just doing straight HDMI-to-HDMI at 1080p to my LG TV seems to work fine, but I have a Dell [WFP2407](http://www.dell.com/downloads/emea/products/snp/UltraSharp%202407WFP_EN.pdf) Monitor connected to the Droibox using a HDMI-DVI cable. The monitor only supports `1920x1200` resolution and I can't get the video to show up using any configuration.

I have tried [various apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nexter.miniscaler) from the store to try and output the required resolution with no luck.

I've also tried moving through all of the options available on the "Display output mode" screen, although it's hard to tell if these options had been applied as I was trying to switch between composite & HDMI output in order to see what I was doing.

[image: Display output mode]

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can change the HDMI output resolution to one of the supported? Or is there some other issue at work here?